# Spring Hateoas / HAL throw Exception

Tags: java, spring, exception, hateoas

I've got weird issue because everything works fine in my application, by after do GET method I always get exception:

```
2018-05-10 12:17:18.608  WARN 16031 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] tion$ResourceSupportHttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson serialization for type [class com.computeralchemist.domain.components.OpinionDto]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot override _serializer: had a `org.springframework.hateoas.hal.Jackson2HalModule$HalLinkListSerializer`, trying to set to `org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$NestedEntitySerializer`
```

My DTO object is simple:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
public abstract class ComputerComponent extends ResourceSupport {

    ....
}
```

And one of child class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Document(collection = "cpu")
public class Cpu extends ComputerComponent {

    @Id
    private long productId;

    private CpuParameters cpuParameters;

}
```

And REST controller's method:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}", produces = "application/json; charset:UTF-8")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public ComputerComponent getComponent(@PathVariable("component") String component,
                                      @PathVariable("id") long id) {

    ComputerComponent computerComponent = repositoryProvider.findComponent(component, id);

    if (computerComponent == null)
        throw new ComponentNotFoundException(component, id);

    computerComponent.add(linkTo(methodOn(ComponentsController.class)
            .getComponent(component, id)).withSelfRel());

    computerComponent.add(linkTo(methodOn(ComponentsController.class)
            .getListOfComponents(computerComponent.getComponentType().toString()))
            .withRel("collection"));

    return computerComponent;
}
```

Json returned (looks correctly, but I don't want null values):

```
{
  "componentType" : "cpu",
  "producent" : "AMD",
  "model" : "Ryzen 5 1600",
    "content" : [ ],
    "links" : [ ]
  },
  "links" : [ {
    "rel" : "self",
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/components/cpu/1",
    "hreflang" : null,
    "media" : null,
    "title" : null,
    "type" : null,
    "deprecation" : null,
    "content" : [ ],
    "links" : [ ]
  }, {
    "rel" : "collection",
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/components/cpu",
    "hreflang" : null,
    "media" : null,
    "title" : null,
    "type" : null,
    "deprecation" : null,
    "content" : [ ],
    "links" : [ ]
  } ]
}
```

PS: Why in Links property is "hreflang","media" etc?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem here. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Hey. This error occur because of DTO inheritance...

Comment: Could you expand - maybe even add an answer: what does "because of DTO inheritance" mean?  How do you make it go away?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is here not so much because it is the answer to the OP's problem (which they seem to have solved) but because it is what caused the problem for me.  So maybe someone else searching for this will be helped...

It appears that if you have:

'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas'

then you have to remove

'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'

At least - that is what solved the problem for me.  The exception went away, as did the null fields that the OP reported.